# preview frames are freezing in camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera2

My requirement is to get a high resolution(~3MP) preview frames at >5fps with camera2 API.

Code snippets:

```
 mPreviewSize = map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)[3];
//this gives roughly around 3MP resolution for ons samsung model.

 previewImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight(),  ImageFormat.JPEG, 2);

previewImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener( mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);
```

---

After fetching the previewframes,I am using image.close() to flush the image.

Now, with this arrangement frames are freezing.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?